# MongoError: collection name must be a String - Even though I specified a string already

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Does anyone have any idea why I'm facing this error even though I've clearly specified 'user' as my collection which is a string? Thank you in advance! (Btw I'm tryna modularise all my database Handler into another js file).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you `console.log("collectionName" + collectionName)` under line 12? I have seen `async` issues in past, so just wondering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `module.exports`, you're executing the function instead of passing a reference to the function. Try this:

```
module.exports = {
  insertHandler: insertHandler
}
```

or using ES6

```
module.exports = {
  insertHandler
}
```